# Problems with div and links/forms

Tags: css, class, html, button

So I have a section in a div to make my left sidebar. Keep in mind I am very new to html. Anyway, there are three buttons currently in this div, but for some reason weebly is telling me that something is wrong with the  tag. Also the link for whichever button comes second keeps showing up in my right div as well. Any ideas why would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
<div id="left">
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/racinbases"><img src="icon" height="50" width="50">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/racinbases"><img src="icon" height="50">
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"     target="_top" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value=(removed for sanity)">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"     border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"     width="1" height="1">
    </form>   
</div>

<div id='right'>

</div>


#left 
{
width: 325px; height: 1000px; float: left; background-color: red;
}

#right 
{
float:right; width: 515px; height: 1000px; background-color: blue;
}
```

'

Comment: Try running your code through an html validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this?

```
 <div id = 'wrapper'>
    <div class = 'fLeft redColor'>
        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com/racinbases"><img src = "icon" height = "50" width = "50"></a>
            <a href = "https://www.facebook.com/racinbases"><img src = "icon" height = "50"></a>
                <form action = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "post" target = "_top" style = "display: inline-block;">
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "cmd" value = "_s-xclick"/>
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "encrypted" value = "encrypted"/>
                    <input type = "image" src = "https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"/>
                    <img alt = "" border = "0" src = "https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width = "1" height = "1"/>
                </form>
    </div>
    <div class = 'fLeft blueColor'>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .fLeft {
        width: 325px;
        height: 1000px;
        float: left;
    }

    .redColor {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .blueColor {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

just saw the code, really messed up.

In your HTML `<a>` are not closed; and in `src` tag define some image extension like: jpg, png.

I recommend using the BUTTON element rather than the INPUT type="image". The BUTTON element is more flexible. You can add images to it, and it can be defined as a submit or reset type of button without needing any extra JavaScript.

Comment: I suggest you to accept this answer by clicking on green checkmark. so other people can get benefits if they facing same problem.